# Leaflet - CanvasLayer: how to get animated features to move correctly when dragging the map?

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet, requestanimationframe

Trying to add a Canvas layer on top of a Bing TileLayer using the extensions below. In addition to that, I would like to animate the canvas drawing using `RequestAnimationFrame`.
The issue is that it seems that when dragging, the point moves more than what it should (see video). However, at the end of the moving, it comes back to the right place.

[image: scrolling map with mouse]

I tried different methods, either inheriting CanvasLayer and overriding render() or setting a delegate, always same result.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
// layer creation (TypeScript)
this.mapCanvasLayer = new L.CanvasLayer();
this.mapCanvasLayer.delegate(this).addTo(map);

// L.canvasLayer()
//     .delegate(this) // -- if we do not inherit from L.CanvasLayer we can setup a delegate to receive events from L.CanvasLayer
//     .addTo(map);

// drawing and animation (TypeScript)
public onDrawLayer(info) {
    // quick test, this just draws a red dot that blinks
    this.info = info;
    var data = [[0,0]];
    var ctx = info.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, info.canvas.width, info.canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0," + this.i/10 + ")";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var d = data[i];
        if (info.bounds.contains([d[0], d[1]])) {
            var dot = info.layer._map.latLngToContainerPoint([d[0], d[1]]);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(dot.x, dot.y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
};

public animate() {
    // make the point blink
    if (this.up) {
        this.i++;
        if (this.i >= 10) this.up = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.i--;
        if (this.i <= 1) this.up = true;
    }

    // animate:
    this.mapCanvasLayer.drawLayer();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
}
```

Extensions tried:

- [gLayers.Leaflet](https://github.com/Sumbera/gLayers.Leaflet) // example is this one
- [Leaflet.CanvasLayer](https://github.com/CartoDB/Leaflet.CanvasLayer)

Not tried yet:

- [Leaflet-Fullcanvas](https://github.com/cyrilcherian/Leaflet-Fullcanvas)

I have the feeling it is due either to the dragging event or the coordinates translations (`latLngToContainerPoint`) not being properly handled, but have no idea why.
In the samples available for the [Leaflet.CanvasLayer](https://github.com/CartoDB/Leaflet.CanvasLayer) dragging an animated map seems to work fine.
Any idea what is wrong with this code? Thank you for your help!

**Edit**

See comments: replaced the call as below:

```
// var dot = info.layer._map.latLngToContainerPoint([d[0], d[1]]);
var dot = info.layer._map.latLngToLayerPoint([d[0], d[1]]);
```

Now, the point moves correctly. However, when I release the button, it now shifts to a position relative to the container, i.e. same distance of window borders, but wrong coordinates (wrong location on map).

If I now do this:

```
public onDrawLayer(info) {
    this.info = info;
    var ctx = info.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, info.canvas.width, info.canvas.height);

    const fillStyleLayer     = "rgba(255,0,0,1)"; // red: layer
    const fillStyleContainer = "rgba(0,0,255,1)"; // blue: container

    var layerPoint     = info.layer._map.latLngToLayerPoint([0,0]);
    var containerPoint = info.layer._map.latLngToContainerPoint([0,0]);

    // this.dot = (this.dragging)
    //     ? info.layer._map.latLngToLayerPoint([0,0]);
    //     : info.layer._map.latLngToContainerPoint([0,0]);

    ctx.fillStyle = fillStyleLayer;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(layerPoint.x, layerPoint.y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.fillStyle = fillStyleContainer;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(containerPoint.x, containerPoint.y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
};

public animate() {
    this.mapCanvasLayer.drawLayer();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
}
```

Layer point (red) moves correctly when panning but then shifts to wrong location. Container point (blue) moves too much when panning but then shifts back to correct location... :(

Comment: does `latLngToContainerPoint` change while you drag the map? I guess the point where you draw should always be the same, as the canvastiles move themselves.

Comment: @RolandStarke yes dot.x and dot.y change; however when I release the mouse, the dot comes back to right place BUT dot.x and dot.y do not seem to shift (i.e. are equal to last position before releasing mouse button). Wonder if it is linked to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/107304/120656

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game but switching to L.canvasOverlay() worked for me. Here's a great example of the library in action

http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/11114288